# Should I make this XmlSerializer static?

Tags: c#, static, xml-serialization, instance

I've got a class which uses an `XmlSerializer` in its `Read/WriteXml` methods. The Serializer is currently `private readonly`.

```
public class Foo : IXmlSerializable
{
    private Bar _bar = new Bar();
    private readonly XmlSerializer serBar = new XmlSerializer (typeof (Bar));

    public void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
    {
        serBar.Serialize (writer, Bar);
    }
    // ...
}
```

I'm considering making the Serializer `private static` instead, so one instance is shared between all Foos. Is this a good idea, or are there possible issues?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, it is a good idea. No, there aren't any issues with it. In particular, thread safety is *not* an issue - from  [MSDN documentation for `XmlSerializer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx):

> Thread Safety
>
> This type is thread safe.

Comment: Ah, great, this is going to be the accepted answer unless something new comes up. :)

Answer (score 16):

According to Neal - even more universal and safe through Generics and readonly:

```
public static class Helper<T>
{
    public static readonly XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
}
```

Use as:

```
Helper<My>.Serializer
```

Answer (score 7):

One way would be to create an XmlSerializers factory and reference it statically (or as an IoC reference), something like:

```
public class XmlSerializerFactory
{
    public XmlSerializer GetSerializerFor<T>()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            Type typeOfT = typeof(T);
            if (false == serializers.ContainsKey(typeOfT))
            {
                XmlSerializer newSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeOfT);
                serializers.Add(typeOfT, newSerializer);
            }

            return serializers[typeOfT];
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<Type, XmlSerializer> serializers = new Dictionary<Type, XmlSerializer>();
}
```

Comment: Very inefficient. PROGrand answer is much better: locking on T1 will not block T2.

Comment: For 99.99% of calls (when serializer already exists), you can add
            if (serializers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
                return serializers[typeof(T)];
BEFOR lock - so not thread locks occur

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  In general you'll want to do this for all of your serializer classes.  It can dramatically speed up your application

The easiest way to do this is:

```
public static class MySerializers {
   public static XmlSerializer MyType = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType));    
}
```

Then when you need a serializer you can simply call:

```
MySerializers.MyType
```

Also note that according to C# semantics, static classes are initialized on first use, not at load-time.  If you want to put all the load cost up front, you'll need to explicitly access the class.